# Having the iOS app awake all the time

Tags: ios

I'm developing an application that has a files downloading feature. Almost all the files that can be downloaded through the app are really big, so the downloading time is quite long.

What I'm trying to develop is a way to keep the app alive, and with alive I mean that the device never gets blocked while the app is opened. I want to write the app so the downloading doesn't stop when the device blocks.

What I found over the internet is that this method violates some Apple policies, but this app won't be in the App Store, so I don't really mind about that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

It won't violate any Apple policy, as it is provided by Apple only.

Cheers.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I think this idleTimerDisabled is legal, but not as the behaviour I'm giving to it. I want the app to stay awake EVERYTIME, and that's what Apple doesn't let you do, but this method is legal, for sure. Thanks for the help!